# Unsuccessfully Running TensorFlow Package on Windows and Python

Tags: python, import, package

I have been working with Anaconda, Python 3.5 and Win 7. Having been obliged to work with TensorFlow, I installed and run it. For the first time it worked but for the second time, I got the error : "tensor flow module not found". I uninstalled and installed it again and got the same error. Switching to windows 10, python 2 or using another system have not been useful.
Is there any other way to try (except using Linux)?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Windows 10, python 3.6 (anaconda) should work fine as long as you use `conda env` - https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows (Installing with Anaconda)

Comment: Thanks, I did the instructions step by step by don't succeed in running tensorflow on Spyder or Jupyter though it has been installed successfully. spyder and jupyter crash down after invoking. I installed all required packages as well. what wrong with it?

Comment: did u activate the env and then try? Sorry little hard to debug with so little information

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Yes, I activated the env and installed spyder and Jupyter for this new env.

Comment: the problem solved. TF is now working on Python 3.5, win 7 and Anaconda 64b.

Comment: post your solution and mark as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change this instruction: `conda create -n tensorflow pip python=3.5`
to: `conda create -n tensorflow pip python=3.5 -spyder`.